# Filter a parent list by a particular child list item's lookup field value

Tags: lookup-column, filter

I have two lists, Activities and Objectives. The Activities list has a multi-value lookup field that references the Objectives list.

I am trying to create a filtered view on the Objectives list that, given a particular Activities item Id, only shows the Objectives that are referenced in that Activities list item's lookup field. I would prefer a solution that can be implemented via SharePoint designer but a custom code solution would work as well.

Comment: This might be better served the other way around. Have a lookup in Objectives to Activities, then you can filter the Objectives list easy enough. Otherwise, I don't think this would be doable without some serious development and basically recreating the list view.

Comment: Unfortunately objectives can be referenced by multiple activities.

Answer (score 0):

Use a workflow which is triggered on the Activities list which inserts the ID of the Activity into a field on the selected objectives.